# Sending form field values to params hash - rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a partial that I call in layouts/application.html.erb to display a form for a search. The user chooses values from the two select fields; then, should hit enter to render a view with search results.

Here is the partial:

** _search.html.erb:

```
<form name="classic">
<select name="countries" size="1" onChange="updatecities(this.selectedIndex)" style="width: 150px">
<option selected>Select A Brand</option>
<option value="usa">Opel</option>
<option value="canada">Cheverolet</option>
<option value="uk">Scoda</option>
</select>

<select name="cities" size="1" style="width: 150px">
</select>

</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

var countrieslist=document.classic.countries
var citieslist=document.classic.cities

var cities=new Array()
cities[0]=""
cities[1]=["Vectra|vectravalue", "Corsa|corsavalue"]
cities[2]=["Optra|optravalue", "Lanos|lanosvalue"]
cities[3]=["Octavia|octaviavalue", "Fleshia|fleshiavalue"]

function updatecities(selectedcitygroup){
citieslist.options.length=0
if (selectedcitygroup>0){
for (i=0; i<cities[selectedcitygroup].length; i++)
citieslist.options[citieslist.options.length]=new Option(cities[selectedcitygroup][i].split("|")[0],         cities[selectedcitygroup][i].split("|")[1])
}
}

</script>
```

The javascript is just to filter the second select dropdown based on the first select dropdown. What I need to do is to send the values chosen in this form in the URL for params hash so that I can act on it in the controller and display the search results. I could use link_to.

How do I include the selected values from the form fields in link_to?

Your help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Serialize the form and send the data to the server. The selected value is passed as the hashvalue where the key is the "id" for the select tag.